# Angular 4 troubleshooting

Tags: angular

> `http://dcwweb.azurewebsites.net/ 
>    username: sw password: sw`

the API is getting hit to get the data on the landing page from google chrome, however the same is not working from any other browser and from my mobile google chrome's browser as well. I have put debugger at the relevant places.

Can someone have a look , and guide me what is getting wrong here.
Probably there is some issue that google chrome is ignoring however other browser aren't

Answer (score 0):

Angular will work properly in most recent browsers. For browsers like IE11, you need to enable polyfills in angular to render angular website in it.

Refer: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

It has details about supported browser and also about polyfills.